# Shopify Custom Shipping Script - Remove Shipping Rates For Specific Product

Tags: ruby, e-commerce, shopify

So I think I am close to getting thi too work

I am trying to add a custom script to remove all shipping options if a particular country and product are selected in the cart.

I thought the below code would work but doesn't seem to be and I am getting no errors

Context -
If a product has a hazmat tag and is outside of the UK then remove all shipping options and display a message "We Cannot Ship to Your Country"

```
    Hazmat_Tag= 'hazmat'

if Input.cart.shipping_address.country_code != 'UK' && Input.cart.line_items.any?{|item| item.variant.product.tags.include? Hazmat_Tag}
  Input.shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|shipping_rate.source == 'shopify'
    break
  end
end

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove all shipping methods but was unable to place a message into the checkout. Were you able to solve this issue?

```
Hazmat_Tag= 'hazmat';
isHazmat = false;

Input.cart.line_items.each do |item| 
  if item.variant.product.tags.include?(Hazmat_Tag)
    isHazmat = true;
    break
  end
end

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|
  if isHazmat && Input.cart.shipping_address.country_code != 'UK'
    shipping_rate
  end
end
```

--OR---

```
Hazmat_Tag= 'hazmat';

if Input.cart.shipping_address.country_code != 'UK' && Input.cart.line_items.any?{|item| item.variant.product.tags.include? Hazmat_Tag}
  Input.shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|
      shipping_rate
  end
end

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates
```

-Edit-
Use GB for United Kingdom. [Shopify Country Code](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/enum/countrycode)

Comment: Same boat with the message.  You ever solve this?

Comment: Hi @RyanMac, I was never able to resolve via scripts but did a workaround with languages instead.... not great... but I used it for a food service client where they couldn't ship to certain states. `/themes/<THEME_ID>/language?query=checkout` I forgot where but its one of them. Another idea would be to explore Shopify's new checkout app extensions.

Comment: Yea, I spoke with Shopify Plus tech support, they pretty much told me it was impossible.

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you for circling back here and letting me know. Most likely they'll want to push Shopify functions. Would be a great use case!